# The component for route router must be a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am facing this error says The component for route 'router' must be a React component. Unable to check on which line it is showing an error.
Any suggestions, thanks 
[image: error]

*App Navigator class*

```
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
    import Login from './src/Login';
    import Fruits from './src/Fruits';
    import FruitZoom from './src/FruitZoom';

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Login: { screen:Login},
      Fruits: { screen: Fruits},
      FruitZoom: { screen: FruitZoom}
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Login',
      headerMode: 'none'
    });

    export default createStackNavigator(AppNavigator);
```

This is generic code using in app, so help me to resolve this issue and what line it is showing an error. Thank you

Comment: Can you include the original error message? to know which component is causing the problem.

Comment: can you show the code of component that is causing the problem?

Comment: This is working solution for above problem:
const Apps = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <Apps />;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the export you are doing inside your App Navigator file. Just export the StackNavigator doing :

```
export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: not working, tried

Comment: This is working solution for above problem:
const Apps = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <Apps />;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #1:**

You might want to consider this:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Login from './src/Login';
import Fruits from './src/Fruits';
import FruitZoom from './src/FruitZoom';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Fruits: { screen: Fruits},
  FruitZoom: { screen: FruitZoom}
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
  headerMode: 'none'
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

You might want to run install the `react-navigation` lib, since it's not listed as a dependency for `react-navigation-stack`:

```
yarn add react-navigation
# or with npm
# npm install react-navigation
```

[As from this.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html#creating-a-stack-navigator)

---

**ORIGINAL Answer:**

From the docs of the `react-navigation-stack`, this is the basic usage for the `createStackNavigator` method:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

export default createStackNavigator({
  Inbox: InboxScreen
  Drafts: DraftsScreen,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Inbox',
});
```

Where in your code, you are doing it twice, at: `const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({.....})` and also in `export default createStackNavigator(AppNavigator)` you may wanna replace that content with:

```
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
    import Login from './src/Login';
    import Fruits from './src/Fruits';
    import FruitZoom from './src/FruitZoom';

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Login: { screen:Login},
      Fruits: { screen: Fruits},
      FruitZoom: { screen: FruitZoom}
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Login',
      headerMode: 'none'
    });

    export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: above solution still not working.

Comment: I have an Update for u.

Comment: @Sulltan.H , I posted my answer below

Comment: It's basically the same concept, but I prefer keeping this isolated as in the updated answer, and keep your App component where it's original at.